# TikZ/Pgf - I can't get "node" to work

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, tikz-node

I'm having trouble with some work and I would appreciate any help. I would like to add this kind of text into my project:

[image: The red arrows indicate what I mean]

And here's my code, I don't know why `node[left]{$P^*=50$}` and `node[below]{$Q^*=500$}` don't display

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis} [axis lines = left, xlabel = $Q$, ylabel = {$P$}]

\addplot [domain=0:960, samples=100, color=green] {0.1*x} node [left] {$CMg$};
\addlegendentry{$0,1\cdot Q$};

\addplot [domain=0:1000, samples=100, color=red] {100-1/10*x} node [above right] {$IMg$};
\addlegendentry{$100-0,1\cdot Q$}

\draw [dashed] (0,50) node[left]{$P^*=50$} -- (500,50) -- (500,0) node[below]{$Q^*=500$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TZeX.SE! Ti options of `axis` you need to add `clip=false`, but as you have designed diagram, node will overwrite diagram's ticks labels.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you! It works :)

Comment: See my answer, in it I also suggest some modifications of your diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let mi spell out my comment ... and add some small modification of your diagram code. You may liked it:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center, 
    xmax=1150, ymax=110,
    xlabel = $Q$, 
    ylabel = $P$,
    label style=right,
    legend style={at={(0.5,1)},legend columns=-1,
                  font=\scriptsize, anchor=north},
    legend cell align=left,
    samples=2, no marks,
    clip=false  % <---
            ]

\addplot +[domain=0:960] {0.1*x} node [right] {$CMg$};
\addplot +[domain=0:1000] {100-1/10*x} node [above right] {$IMg$};
\legend{${100-0,1{\cdot}Q}$,  ${0,1{\cdot}Q}$};

\draw[dashed]   (-2pt,   50) node[left, font=\footnotesize]{$P^*{=}50$} -| 
                (500,-2.5ex) node[below,font=\footnotesize]{$Q^*=500$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!! Those are some great modifications! I didn't know you could change those things, it looks so much better now

Comment: @Tomás, you are velcome!